How to join part of an interface between components?
I would like to examine the problem of two beams glued together when the glue does not cover all of the interface. I wish to know the effect on the natural frequencies of the beams.
To warm up I model two beams fully joined at the interface.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
ClearAll[t, u, v, w];
Len1 = 0.25; (*Length of beam 1*)
Len2 = 0.25; (*Length of beam 2*)
wth = 0.03;  (* Width of beams*)
tk = 0.01; (* Thickness of beams *)


beam1 = Cuboid[{0, -wth/2, 0}, {Len1, wth/2, tk}];
beam2 = Cuboid[{Len1 - wth, -wth/2, -tk}, {Len1 - wth + Len2, wth/2, 
    0}];
Graphics3D[{beam1, beam2},
 Axes -> True]


geom = RegionUnion[beam1, beam2];
mesh = ToElementMesh[geom];
pars = <|"YoungModulus" -> 210 10^9, "PoissonRatio" -> 3/10, 
   "MassDensity" -> 7850, "AnalysisType" -> "Eigenmode"|>;
vars = {{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, t, {x, y, z}};
ps = SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[vars, pars];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall] = 
  SolidFixedCondition[x == 0, vars, pars];
{vals, vecs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{ps == {0, 0, 0}, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
    wall]}, {u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, 
   t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 4];
1/(2 \[Pi]) Sqrt[vals]

(* {37.7233, 111.539, 234.854, 652.039} *)

This has all worked nicely to give me the beam natural frequencies. I can now plot the mode shapes (eigen shapes).
Table[
 Show[MeshRegion[
   ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, vecs[[n]], "ScalingFactor" -> 0.05]], 
  ElementMeshEdgeframe3D[mesh],
  ImageSize -> 6 72],
 {n, Length@vals}]


The interface was completely joined. I now wish to try to join it within a small circular region as if the glue had not spread out completely. Can this be done directly? For example can I join within a disc with the following specification:
r = wth/4;(*Radius of joining disc*)
c0 = {Len1 - wth/2, 0, 0}; (* Centre of joining disc *)

I have been looking at OpenCascade; that gives union of faces (I don't want a whole face) or sewing (which seems to be between whole components). I just want part of a face. I looked at splitting but I don't see how to split without separating the two faces.
Thanks for any ideas.

what about putting a thin cylindrical region or disc between the two beams? You may have issues potentially with contact between the unglued beam areas, but maybe this is a start.

@dunlop Yes this is something I have considered. If very thin then there are numerical problems with a disc. If not thin then this is will change the natural frequencies in a different way to the one I am studying. Interpenetration of surfaces and gapping are features I wish to study.  Thanks for the comment.

Here are a couple of ways to do it. Let's start with the definitions:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
ClearAll[t, u, v, w];
Len1 = 0.25; (*Length of beam 1*)
Len2 = 0.25; (*Length of beam 2*)
wth = 0.03;  (*Width of beams*)
tk = 0.01; (*Thickness of beams*)


beam1 = Cuboid[{0, -wth/2, 0}, {Len1, wth/2, tk}];
beam2 = Cuboid[{Len1 - wth, -wth/2, -tk}, {Len1 - wth + Len2, wth/2, 0}];

geom = RegionUnion[beam1, beam2];


r = wth/4;(*Radius of joining disc*)
c0 = {Len1 - wth/2, 0, 0}; (*Centre of joining disc*)

bmgr = ToBoundaryMesh[geom]["Wireframe"]


Idea 1
The first idea is to implant a two small cylinders at the connection of the beams. One for each beam.
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{Len1 - wth/2, 0, 0}, {Len1 - wth/2, 0, tk/2}}, r];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{Len1 - wth/2, 0, -tk/2}, {Len1 - wth/2, 0, 0}}, r];
Show[bmgr, Graphics3D[{cyl1, cyl2}], 
 PlotRange -> {{Len1 - 2 wth, Len1 + wth}, All, All}]


s1 = OpenCascadeShape[beam1];
s2 = OpenCascadeShape[beam2];
s3 = OpenCascadeShape[cyl1];
s4 = OpenCascadeShape[cyl2];
u1 = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[s1, s3];
u2 = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[s2, s4];

Let's look at one of them:
bm = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[u1];
bm["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {{Len1 - 2 wth, Len1 + wth}, All, All}]]


Then combine all faces:
f1 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[u1];
f2 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[u2];
shape = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[Flatten[{f1, f2}]];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape];
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  PlotRange -> {{Len1 - 2 wth, Len1 + wth}, All, All}]]


What follows next, is identifying the disk element marker to be able to specify boundary conditions there.
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[Opacity[0.1], FaceForm[#]] & /@ 
     colors), PlotRange -> {{Len1 - 2 wth, Len1 + wth}, All, All}]]


And the actual marker can then be found by going through the list (or use a Manipulate if there are more faces)
bmesh["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == 8]]


Idea 2
This implants a Disk at the interface.
d3D = Disk3D[{c0, {0, 0, 1}}, r];
gr = Show[Graphics3D[d3D], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
Show[bmgr, gr, PlotRange -> {{Len1 - 2 wth, Len1 + wth}, All, All}]


s = OpenCascadeShape[geom];
f1 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[s];
f2 = OpenCascadeShape[OpenCascadeDisk[{c0, {0, 0, 1}}, r]];
shape = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[Flatten[{f1, f2}]];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape];
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  PlotRange -> {{Len1 - 2 wth, Len1 + wth}, All, All}]]


You can the use the same technique as above to find the ElementMarker of the Disk.
Idea 3
In this idea we extrude faces that have the appropriate disk as a boundary to 3D.
face1 = Rectangle[{0, -wth/2}, {Len1, wth/2}];
disk = Disk[{Len1 - wth/2, 0}, r];
Graphics[{Directive[FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black]], face1, disk}]


f1 = OpenCascadeShape[face1];
d = OpenCascadeShape[disk];
base = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[f1, d];
sweep1 = 
  OpenCascadeShapeLinearSweep[
   base, {{Len1 - wth/2, 0, 0}, {Len1 - wth/2, 0, tk/2}}];
bm = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep1];
bm["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {{Len1 - 2 wth, Len1 + wth}, All, All}]]


face2 = Rectangle[{Len1 - wth, -wth/2}, {Len1 - wth + Len2, wth/2}];
disk = Disk[{Len1 - wth/2, 0}, r];
Graphics[{Directive[FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black]], face2, disk}]


And then again combine all faces:
allFaces = Flatten[OpenCascadeShapeFaces /@ {sweep1, sweep2}];
shape = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[allFaces];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape];
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  PlotRange -> {{Len1 - 2 wth, Len1 + wth}, All, All}]]


And again, to find the ElementMarker of the Disk, you can use the approach of Idea 1. This approach has the disadvantage that you have a cylinder in the geometry, that you do not need; but it does not hurt either.
Hope this helps.

Thanks. As usual a solution. Is there always a solution! The method for making a zero thickness interface looks good and I will explore this further.

Yes, I think there is always a solution:-) My problem is, that it's too hard to find. Let me know which of the solutions you used and what worked.

Please could you give me the next stage. How do  I do a union making sure that element  8 is joined but the surrounding element is not joined?

I'd think then you need a gap - the glue does have an extend in the z direction. But let me think a bit more about this.
